# Как написать значения на ползунке?

Tags: canvas

[image: Ползунок без значений]

***   Ползунок без значений    ***

Comment: Что это за ползунок? из `input type=range`? Что надо добавить? Выложите код ползунка в его теперешнем виде.

Comment: @Leonid,<input id="slider" type="range" list="rangelist" min = "0" max="200" name "range" value "150" step "1">, нужно добавить обозначения для ползунка -90;0+90, которые не будут зависеть от настоящего значения слайдера

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/range здесь можете посмотреть